# Problems with defining paths for multiple bundles via webpack-dev-server

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to create multiple (but very similiar) react apps with one webpack config. Let's say this is my directory structure:

```
├── src
│   ├── app01
│   │   └── app01.js
│   ├── app02
│   │   └── app02.js
│   └── shared-components
│       ├── Logo
│       │   ├── Logo.js
│       ├── Nav
│       │   ├── Nav.js
├── dist
│   ├── app01
│   │   ├── app01.html
│   ├── app02
│   │   └── app02.html
```

In webpack.config.js I have this:

```
var config = {
//cut for brevity 
},
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist/',
    colors: true,
    inline: true
  }
}

var app1 = Object.assign({}, config, {
  name: 'app1',
  entry: './src/app1/app1',
  output: {
    path: './dist/app1',
    publicPath: '/app1/',
    filename: 'bundle1.js'
  }
})

var app2 = Object.assign({}, config, {
  name: 'app2',
  entry: './src/app2/app2',
  output: {
    path: './dist/app2',
    publicPath: '/app2/',
    filename: 'bundle2.js'
  }
})

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  config.devtool = false
   config.plugins = [
   new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
     new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({comments: false}),
     new webpack.DefinePlugin({
     'process.env': {NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')}
   })
 ]
}

module.exports = [app1, app2]
```

When I run my build script, webpack works and creates relevant js files in relevant folders. So: `bundle1.js` in `dist/app1` directory and `bundle2.js` in `dist/app2` directory. However I have problems with webpack-dev-server. When I run webpack-dev-server it serves both `bundle1.js` and `bundle2.js` from `dist/app1`. If I remove `output.publicPath` properties from `app1` and `app2` objects webpack-dev-server serves `bundle1.js` and `bundle2.js` from my `dist` directory.

How should I edit my webpack config to tell webpack-dev-server to serve relevant bundles in relevant directories?